# which python function to use to run bash script on remote server? subprocess.Popen, call? new to python

Tags: python, bash, call, popen

I am running on python 2.7.5. I am converting some bash script to python (learning as I coding) and I'm confused on which is the better solution?  I need to copy files to a remote server and then run a script on that remote server using the file.  I was using Popen

```
ssh = subprocess.Popen(["ssh", desthost, "cd {}; {} {}".format(remote_dir, scriptname, filename)]
```

But it doesn't read my cd.  I see that I can use call but I am not clear on if I can get error output from it like I could if I used popen. I keep seeing fabric being mentioned but I didn't know it this could really be done in a one liner.  Any advice is appreciated.

Comment: You should use the Paramiko library to use ssh from Python.

Comment: You shouldn't be using Python 2.x, it has been EOLed. Upgrade to 3.x.

Comment: The `ssh` command inherits its standard output and standard error from your Python process itself. See the documentation for the `subprocess` module for how to create a pipe the `ssh` will write to and your Python code can read from instead.

Comment: @Barmar, you're right, I did not notice the `ssh`,  I will delete my comment to not confuse others.

Comment: Thanks, I had the sys admins upgrade my python version. I will look at paramiko again.  It seemed to be overkill for the commands i needed.